# pass numpy 2D double complex array to cython as memoryview

Tags: python, numpy, cython, cythonize, memoryview

The following code fails in a jupyter notebook. However if I work with double instead of double complex, everything works correctly.

```
%%cython 
cpdef test_array(double complex [:,::1] test):
    cdef int x1,y1 
    x1,y1 = test.shape[0],test.shape[1]
    for i in range(x1):
        for j in range(y1):
            test[i][j]+=0
```

The error for double complex is :

```
/home/sajid/.cache/ipython/cython/_cython_magic_b61ff75cef6df4a7db32aeafc6c3f9ff.c: In function '__pyx_f_46_cython_magic_b61ff75cef6df4a7db32aeafc6c3f9ff_test_array':
/home/sajid/.cache/ipython/cython/_cython_magic_b61ff75cef6df4a7db32aeafc6c3f9ff.c:2149:183: error: invalid operands to binary + (have '__pyx_t_double_complex {aka struct <anonymous>}' and '__pyx_t_double_complex {aka struct <anonymous>}')
       *((__pyx_t_double_complex *) ( /* dim=1 */ ((char *) (((__pyx_t_double_complex *) ( /* dim=0 */ (__pyx_v_test.data + __pyx_t_17 * __pyx_v_test.strides[0]) )) + __pyx_t_18)) )) += __pyx_t_double_complex_from_parts(0, 0);
                                                                                                                                                                                       ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/sajid/.cache/ipython/cython/_cython_magic_b61ff75cef6df4a7db32aeafc6c3f9ff.c: In function '__pyx_f_46_cython_magic_b61ff75cef6df4a7db32aeafc6c3f9ff_test_array':
/home/sajid/.cache/ipython/cython/_cython_magic_b61ff75cef6df4a7db32aeafc6c3f9ff.c:2149:183: error: invalid operands to binary + (have '__pyx_t_double_complex {aka struct <anonymous>}' and '__pyx_t_double_complex {aka struct <anonymous>}')
       *((__pyx_t_double_complex *) ( /* dim=1 */ ((char *) (((__pyx_t_double_complex *) ( /* dim=0 */ (__pyx_v_test.data + __pyx_t_17 * __pyx_v_test.strides[0]) )) + __pyx_t_18)) )) += __pyx_t_double_complex_from_parts(0, 0);
```

I'd need to use numpy outside the function and pass it as a memoryview to enable parallel operations with nogil.

Comment: You probably right to assume, that this is a bug: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2512

Comment: Thanks! I guess one needs to be very careful about type casting in cython then.